# How to hide the row if it has no children in kendo-treeview in angular 8?

Tags: angular8, kendo-treeview

How to hide the parent row if it has no children to display.text i can hide it but Empty row still present in the DOM element. Can anyone help to get it resolved? angular 8 + kendo treeview.

```
<kendo-treeview kendoTreeViewExpandable [nodes]="data" [children]="children" [hasChildren]="hasChildren" textField="text"
     >
        <ng-template kendoTreeViewNodeTemplate let-dataItem>
               <span>{{dataitem.title}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-treeview>
```

Answer (score 0):

Backend side, I have a parent row looking like this :

```
{
    id: "session_client_1669"
    id_linked: "1669"
    id_regroup: null
    libelle: "UN CLIENT PRESQUE PARFAIT"
    menu: "client"
    type: "parent"
}
```

Then, a child row taking for id_regroup its parent's id :

```
{
    id: "new_DOC_RAPPORT_SESSION_1669"
    idLinked: "1669"
    id_regroup: "session_client_1669"
    libelle: "Document à générer - Rapport de fin de formation"
    menu: "client"
    type: "generated"
}
```

Finally I use a function to recursively filter out elements of parent type with no children, thus getting rid of it in the DOM:

```
function removeEmptyParent(listDoc) {
  try {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
      let listDocTemp = (listDoc || []).filter(
        item =>
          (listDoc.findIndex(e => e.id_regroup === item.id) !== -1 && item.type === 'parent') || item.type !== 'parent',
      );
      const index = (listDocTemp || []).findIndex(
        item => listDocTemp.findIndex(e => e.id_regroup === item.id) === -1 && item.type === 'parent',
      );
      if (index > -1) {
        listDocTemp = await removeEmptyParent(listDocTemp);
      }
      resolve(listDocTemp);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error`, error); // eslint-disable-line
  }
}
```